# How to get event from components to container in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux. 
I handled the basic Facebook Flux architecture very easily and made some nice app with it.
But I struggle very hard to get very simple Redux App to work.
My main concern is about containers and the way they catch events from components.

I have this very simple App :

CONTAINER

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {changevalue} from 'actions'
import App from 'components/App'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    selector:state.value
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onClick: (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      dispatch(changeValue())
    }
  }
}

const AppContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

export default AppContainer;
```

Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Selector from 'components/Selector'
import Displayer from 'components/Displayer'


const App = (selector, onClick) => (
  <div>
    <Selector onClick={(e) => onClick}/>
    <Displayer />
  </div>
)

export default App;
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


const Selector = ({onClick}) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>click me</div>
)

export default Selector;
```

onClick event does not reach the container's mapDispatchToProps. 
I feel that if I get this work, I get a revelation, and finally get the Redux thing!  ;)

Can anybody help me get this, please ? (The Redux doc is TOTALLY NOT helpfull...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the App component. In the `onClick` property of the Selector component, you're passing a function which returns the *definition* of a function, not the result.

```
const App = (selector, onClick) => (
  <div>
    <Selector onClick={(e) => onClick}/> // here is the problem
    <Displayer />
  </div>
)
```

You should simply do this instead:

```
const App = (selector, onClick) => (
  <div>
    <Selector onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}/>
    <Displayer />
  </div>
)
```

Or even simpler:

```
const App = (selector, onClick) => (
  <div>
    <Selector onClick={onClick}/>
    <Displayer />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: This is it ! Thank you.